# media query not working for mobile devices

Tags: css

I have a class for which, the media query is as follows:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 374px) {
  width: 62px;
}

@media only screen and (max-height: 413px) and (min-width: 375px) {
  width: 75px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 414px) {
  width: 85px;
}
```

The middle media query does not seems to work.
Note: the media query is for mobile devices

Comment: You didn't specify any class or tag that you want to apply the styles to

Comment: Is that meant to be `max-height`? looks like you mean width

Comment: Post your full file, may we can help

Comment: Is that SCSS? The syntax would be valid SCSS if you put it inside a declaration block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add `max-height`, all you need to `max-width`, there is standard sizes for mobile phones [check this article here and how it work](https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/), so all you need to add just push your classes inside queries for example:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 374px) {
  .class{
     //style here will display on sizes from 0px to 374px
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 375px) {
  .class{
     //style here will display start display from 375px
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 414px) {
  .class{
     //style here will display start sizes from 414px
  }
}
```

[Check this](https://responsivedesign.is/develop/browser-feature-support/media-queries-for-common-device-breakpoints/) also contain almost of media queries sizes

Full Example:

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>

<body>

    <h1>Media Queries Examples</h1>
    <p>Increase or decrease the size of your window to see the background color change</p>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
p{
 font-family: arial,san-serif;   
    font-size: 13px;
    font-color: black;
}

h1{
 font-size:30px;   
}

@media screen and (min-width:761px){
    body{
    background-color:white;
}
 h1{
    color:red;
}    
}

@media screen and (max-width:760px){
       body{ background-color: #333;
    }
 h1{
    color:red;
}  
p{
    color: white;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width:480px){
       body{ background-color: #807f83;
    }
 h1{
    color:white;
}  
p{
    color: white;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width:360px){
       body{ background-color: #0096d6;
    }
 h1{
    color:white;
    font-size:25px;
}  
p{
    color: white;
}
}
```

[And this is fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DrSRT/)

Comment: I've added a full example, I think you forget to add `<meta>` tag, so please check the example and I recommend to remove max-height, I've updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comment, you need to specify the element which you want to apply styles to. An example would be:

```
@media screen and (max-width:1000px){
 .your-class{
   height:100px;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify the class name in media query to which you want to apply the style.

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 374px) {
    .your_class_name {
      width: 62px;
     }
    }
    @media only screen and (max-height: 413px) and (min-width: 375px) {
      .your_class_name {
        width: 75px;
      }
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width: 414px) {
      .your_class_name {
        width: 85px;
      }
    }
```